# How to remove "Search and launch"?

Tags: kubuntu, customization, plasma-netbook

Is it possible to remove the "Search and launch" whateveritis from my "desktop"? I've actually tried both Desktop and Netbook modes, but it stays there in both of them.
I'm not afraid of editing files in the ~/.kde dir, but I would be really disappointed if this is the only way to do it.

[more details/rants]
I was able to wipe out several things but I've ended up with a black window that's movable (Alt-click) but not removable.

Beside being surprised by the performances, I find Kubuntu *extremely* unfriendly, and I can't find the logic behind the items of the interface. I've tried to search for documentation, but what I've found is not updated and doesn't include the Netbook interface.

Answer (score 2):

Right-click the Search and Launch. Click "Configure Search and Launch". Under the "View" option, click "Layout" and select "Default Desktop". No more Search and Launch!